# How do I set up a ComboBox to equal a certain Column for a UserForm?

Tags: excel, vba

I am still pretty new to VBA but I am creating a UserForm that will input data in. But I also want to have a ComboBox in the UserForm representing the months. And each month suppose to represent a column. For example, if I pick January on the UserForm, then it will put data on the K column. 
I want 1 to 12 to represent Column I to T

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lrCal As Long

lrCal = sheets("TestCal").Cells(7,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1 

With sheets("TestCal")
     .Cells(7, lrCal).Value = tbApple.Text
     .Cells(8, lrCal).Value = tbOrange.Text
     .Cells(12,lrCal).Value = tbBread.Text
     .Cells(13,lrCal).Value = tbJam.Text 
End With

End Sub
```

Right now it is going to the next available cell. But I want it to go to the column that I pick.

```
Private Sub cboMonth_Change()

dim cboMonth as ComboBox
dim i as long
dim ws as worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.sheets("TestCal")


For i = 1 to 12

Next
```

I am stuck on this part, do not know how to set it up. How would I set up each number to represent each column?

Comment: Use `Range().Find` to find your column

Comment: Have you populated your Userform via `Userform_Initialize` using the range or by other means?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your approach to populating your combobox, there are numerous ways to do this... one example would be to populate your combobox so that you can relate the list-position to a column, e.g.:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Debug.Print Application.Match(ComboBox1.Value, ComboBox1.List, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Sheets(1)
        Me.ComboBox1.List = Array("Jan","Feb","Mar")
    End With
End Sub
```

You can test the above and see that the List position (the location number in the array) is displayed in the immediate window.

---

So if January is in column 11 (K), you can output your data like:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    '11-1 = 10, you would need to find last row in column for this:
    Sheets(1).Cells(LastRow+1,10+Application.Match(ComboBox1.Value, ComboBox1.List, 0)).value = Me.TextBox1.Value
End Sub
```

You could also do this without the combobox using `Match()` or `Find()`.